# How to a make a specific tumblr page have a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, grid, tumblr

My Tumblr is http://00100101.com. 
I want a 3 units grid view on one page http://00100101.com/store
I would like to keep the general format of the overall entire website (sidebar), just change the view of the content of my store page

I have tried the adding custom CSS on Tumblr, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your posts are wrapped in `div#entries` and each post has `.posts` class, so to form a 3 columns grid use this.

Edit: To apply this to store page.

```
body.store .text > center {
    width:33.334%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
}
body.store .posts img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and add `class="store"` to your `<body>` like

```
<body class="store">
```

and here's the output for above CSS

[image]

Note that you need to edit `.posts` in your HTML

Comment: but how do I do it only for that page...when i change the .post it made a grid theme for all pages with content

Comment: please see the store page, the content isn't 3 grid

Comment: You structure is sort of wrong because it doesn't match the one I created. How are you generating the content for your page?

Comment: Store Content: <a href="http://paypal.me/00100101/25"><img src="https://40.media.tumblr.com/4ad84eff12df445c794901164b4d4362/tumblr_inline_nxhkcasg391ryqqko_500.jpg"/></a>

<p>A 3 piece conceptual digest based on findings from Japan, </p>
<p>including a physical photo book, short film, and digital scrapbook.</p>

Comment: Hey can you help me still?

Comment: Yes, I will go over your HTML structure and edit my CSS accordingly.

Comment: @Goeiekarma, see the updated answer, note this will not let any gap (space) between each post. So you should change your HTML based on the CSS I wrote in original version of my answer :)